# Updates failure

Tags: updates, appcenter, apt

I am not able to update my system for a long time. This is the failure text:

```
Failed to fetch http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter/dists/xenial/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.elementary.io_appcenter_dists_xenial_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.xz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 104.28.4.44 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you,

Tamas

Comment: I'm made to believe you are attempting the update via Terminal. Would it be possible for you to edit your post with an upload of a screenshot of your terminal window?

Comment: That's my problem too. Please help us.

Answer (score 1):

I already know the key because I searched on the internet and found it.

Use this in terminal: `sudo apt-get clean`

Then you can use the update command.

Let me know was it good or not.

Thank you

Tamas